# How to align object by bounding box in FabricJS?

Tags: fabricjs

Wondering if there is a way to align objects in FabricJs by their bounding box?

I'm using obj.getBoundingRect() function to determine objects bounders, then compare them with a bounding box (BB) coordinates of an Active one (that one which I move). If I see that something falls between some gap (let's say 10px) I assign an active object top to be the same top as a comparable element by using a .setTop() property.

The problem is that TOP is not a right attribute to use, since the top of the bounding box may differ between elements. For example, 2 elements with the same top but different angle will have different Bounding Box Top...

Hope you see my point...

https://jsfiddle.net/redlive/hwcu1p4f/

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
//fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;

var red = new fabric.Rect({
 id: 1,
  left: 100,
  top: 50,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'red',
  angle: 0,
  padding: 10
});
canvas.add(red);

var green = new fabric.Rect({
 id: 2,
  left: 250,
  top: 180,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'green',
  angle: 45,
  padding: 10
});
canvas.add(green);
canvas.renderAll();

canvas.on("object:moving", function(e){
 const draggableObj = e.target;
  const draggableObjBound = draggableObj.getBoundingRect();
  
  canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
    if (obj.id !== draggableObj.id) {
      var bound = obj.getBoundingRect();
      if (draggableObjBound.top > bound.top - 10 && draggableObjBound.top < bound.top + 10) {
        draggableObj.setTop(obj.getTop());
      }
    }
  });
});

canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
  var setCoords = obj.setCoords.bind(obj);
  obj.on({
    moving: setCoords,
    scaling: setCoords,
    rotating: setCoords
  });
});

canvas.on('after:render', function() {
  canvas.contextContainer.strokeStyle = '#555';
  canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
    var bound = obj.getBoundingRect();
    canvas.contextContainer.strokeRect(
      bound.left,
      bound.top,
      bound.width,
      bound.height
    );
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.0.0-rc.3/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the center to align them, that is not gonna change.

to align the bounding box at left 5 for example:

1) calculate bounding box.
2) set the position of the object to 5 + bb.width/2 considering center.

In this case the bounding rects get aligned.

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
//fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;

var red = new fabric.Rect({
 id: 1,
  left: 100,
  top: 50,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'red',
  angle: 0,
  padding: 10
});
canvas.add(red);

var green = new fabric.Rect({
 id: 2,
  left: 250,
  top: 180,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'green',
  angle: 45,
  padding: 10
});
canvas.add(green);

//ALIGN EVERYTHING TO 5
canvas.forEachObject(function(object) {
  var bb = object.getBoundingRect();
  object.setPositionByOrigin({ x: 5 + bb.width/2, y: bb.top }, 'center', 'center');
  object.setCoords();
});


canvas.renderAll();


canvas.on("object:moving", function(e){
 const draggableObj = e.target;
  const draggableObjBound = draggableObj.getBoundingRect(true, true);
  
  canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
    if (obj.id !== draggableObj.id) {
      var bound = obj.getBoundingRect(true, true);
      if (draggableObjBound.top > bound.top - 10 && draggableObjBound.top < bound.top + 10) {
        draggableObj.setPositionByOrigin({ x: draggableObj.left, y: bound.top + draggableObjBound.height/2 }, draggableObj.originX, 'center');
      }
    }
  });
});

canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
  var setCoords = obj.setCoords.bind(obj);
  obj.on({
    moving: setCoords,
    scaling: setCoords,
    rotating: setCoords
  });
});

canvas.on('after:render', function() {
  canvas.contextContainer.strokeStyle = '#555';
  canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
    var bound = obj.getBoundingRect(true, true);
    canvas.contextContainer.strokeRect(
      bound.left,
      bound.top,
      bound.width,
      bound.height
    );
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.0.0-rc.3/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Comment: Throws error `obj.getTop is not a function` and same `draggableObj.setTop  is not a function`

Comment: throws as much as the original fiddle. the purpose of the code was to add the alignment part. do you think i should fix it all? i can...

Comment: Sorry, guess its bug in 2.0, set/get method not working properly

Comment: Not a bug setTop, getTop  and the others are optional in 2.0. you have to explicitly require them

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi Thank you for your code.
I didn't get what //ALIGN EVERYTHING TO 5 stands for?
What is it 5? I need to align the only DRAGGABLE object with rest...

Comment: it was just supposed to show you how to align some boundingboxes togheter. 5 was a value like any other